# How to say "Comes along with ____."?

Tags: grammar, translation

Example:
Comes along with chopsticks.

I think "箸があります。" is not enough.

Thank you.

Comment: "Sushi box comes along with chopsticks", "A certificate of authenticity comes along with chopsticks", "Peter comes along, with chopsticks" Which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about...

- XXがついてきます。
- XXがついています。
- XXが[入]{はい}っています。
- XX[付]{つ}きです。
- XX[入]{い}りです。
- XX付き
- XX[入]{い}り

Examples:

> 「お弁当には、(お)箸がついています。」
>   「(お)箸が[入]{はい}っています。」
>   「(お)箸[付]{つ}きです。」
>   「(お)箸[入]{い}り」
>   「(お)箸付き」
>   「このお菓子を買うと、おまけがついてきます。」
>   「１２月号を買うと、付録として特製オリジナルバッグがもれなくついてきます。」